# Why my python while code has a syntax error

Tags: python, while-loop

I tried to program to output this:

> > > Write something: What?
> > >       What?
> > >       Write something: Fight the power.
> > >       Fight the power.
> > >       Write something: quit
> > >       Bye bye!
> > >
> > > but there's some problem with my code

```
i = input("Write something:")

while i != "quit":
    print(i)

    if i == "quit":
        print("Bye bye!")
        break
```

It says I have a syntax error
Edit *It was my fault for forgetting the parentheses but I added in and it says that my program doesn't operate correctly. I'm using an academic online console*

Comment: `print("Bye bye!")` ?

Comment: Does it say what line the syntax error is on? Or give any more information at all?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: what is your python version? You're using `print` with and without parentheses

Comment: what is the error message??

Answer (score 2):

Result of while loop in your code getting **infinite loop** in case if input is other than 'quit', may be due to this you are getting ***program doesn't operate correctly*** message. You can consider below code:-

```
i = input("Write something:")
while True:
    if i != "quit":
        print(i)
        i = input("Write something:")
    elif i == "quit":
        print("Bye bye!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `()` around your `print` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hi. You can look at the error you had and line. Problem is that your `print` method has no parenthesis. Either, if it's `python 2.7`, then there is a problem in `print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` evaluates the user input. You want:

```
i = raw_input("Write something:")
```

instead